# Image AJAX search not working in Safari

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, safari

I have a live image search that uses AJAX and an SQL query to find images with a name the same as the users input on a text field. I thought it was working fine until I tested in Safari, and it does literally nothing.

I'm not too sure why not even an error is returned in Safari, does anyone know of an issue in Safari that might be stopping it from working?

jQuery:

```
var input = $('.image-search');
var value;

var append = $(".results-append");
var loadUrl = '/stock-image-search.php';

var results = $('.results');

var resultsDiv = '<div class="results-heading"><h2>Results for "<span class="results-for"></span>"</h2></div>';
var resultsFor;

var nothingFound = '<div class="nothing-found"><br /><span>No results found.</span></div>'


// on keyup
input.on("keyup", function() {

    // remove everything that was there
    $('.results-append').remove();
    results.empty();
    $("#temp_load").remove();

    value = input.val();
    append.prepend(resultsDiv);

    resultsFor = $('.results-for');
    resultsFor.html($(this).val());

    // ajax the results!
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            nameLike: value
        },
        dataType: "html",
        url: templateDir + loadUrl,
        beforeSend: function() {
            append.hide().append('' +
                '<div id="temp_load" class="search-loader">' +
                    '<img src="' + templateDir + '/img/load.GIF" />' +
                '</div>'
            ).fadeIn(200);
        },
        success: function(data) {

            $("#temp_load").fadeOut(200);

            // fix for fast typers
            results.empty();

            var data = $(data);
            if (data.length) {
                results.append(data);
            } else {
                results.append(nothingFound);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#temp_load").fadeOut(200).remove();
            console.log(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

PHP function:

```
<?php

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;

if( isset($_GET['nameLike']) && strlen($_GET['nameLike']) > 1 ) :


    $search = $_GET['nameLike'];

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT ID 
        FROM $wpdb->posts 
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'inherit' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_mime_type != ''
        AND ( $wpdb->posts.post_author = 1 OR $wpdb->posts.post_author = 3 ) 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s 
   ", '%' . like_escape($search) . '%'
   ), ARRAY_A);


   foreach ($results as $result) : ?>


        <?php
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $result[ID], array(200, 150) );
        ?>

        <div class="grid-1-4 clearfix">
            <div class="stock-image-select clearfix" data-id="<?php echo $result[ID]; ?>">
                <?php echo $image; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach;


else : ?>

    <div class="grid-10">Your search needs to be at least 2 characters long.</div>          

<?php endif; ?>
```

If anyone can see a glaring error, please let me know :)

Comment: Have you tried keypress or keyup? http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: Just tried this, no luck still :(

Comment: Put a console.log in the binding to see if it fires up when a key is pressed ... $('something').keyup(function(e){ console.log('here');}...); if it fires in the browser`s console[Press CTRL + ALT + I ] then the JS is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input[name="search_field"]').keyup(function(e){
       $(this).text;  
       //process your search 
        });
});
```

When you detect a key was raised then take the text and do the search.